# Erlang send parenthesized data

Tags: erlang

I am implementing robo soccer agent in Erlang. I am   Unable to send data like

> **(init myteam (version 14))**

or

> **(kick Power Angle)**

to Robocup Soccer simulator Server where Power and Angle are variables having some value[using **gen_udp**]. Compiler is showing syntactical error. (**Parentheses are part of data**)
.

What i want is to send this Data to server

> ok = gen_udp:send(Socket, "localhost",
>   Port,
>                         **Data**)

where Data has to be exactly like above shown 2 examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, you should really show code for stuff like this but:

```
kick(Power, Angle) ->
  io_lib:format("(kick ~B ~B)", [Power, Angle]).

init() ->
   init(myteam, 14).

init(Team, Version) ->
  io_lib:format("(init ~p (version ~B))", [Team, Version]).
```

Is a way to get started (not tested). If you want a faster output, you should probably write a function `term_to_sexp` and then output arbitrary terms as `iolist()`'s (Look up iolists, they are very good for this kind of work and awfully fast).

```
term_to_sexp(A) when is_atom(A) ->
  L = atom_to_list(A),
  <<L>>;
term_to_sexp(B) when is_binary(B) ->
  B;
term_to_sexp(T) when is_tuple(T) ->
  term_to_sexp(tuple_to_list(T));
... % Missing cases probably
term_to_sexp(L) when is_list(L) ->
  intersperse(" ", [term_to_sexp(Item) || Item <- L]).

intersperse(_, []) -> [];
intersperse(_, [X]) -> [X];
intersperse(Sep, [X | Rest]) ->
  [X, Sep | intersperse(Sep, Rest)].
```

(Also not tested, but a start).